# return only " from the selected expression

Tags: regex

I have a regex rule `[A-Z|a-z]"[A-Z|a-z]`.

When applying it to

```
Mother"s day passed!
```

the regex returns `r"s`, but I'm only interested in the `"` char that has to fall in the middle of alphabetic characters.

How can I do that with regex?

Comment: Use `(?<=[A-Za-z])"(?=[A-Za-z])`

Comment: This worked! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use lookarounds, a lookbehind coupled with a lookahead:

```
(?<=[A-Za-z])"(?=[A-Za-z])
```

Here, `(?<=[A-Za-z])` positive lookbehind will require a letter on the left and the `(?=[A-Za-z])` positive lookahead will require a letter to the right of the double quotation mark.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vh1YBB/1).

BTW, note that `[A-Z|a-z]` matches ASCII letters *and* a `|` char, since the `|` inside a character class loses its special meaning of an alternation operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Positive Lookbehind as below

```
(?<=\b)"
```

`\b` assert position at a word boundary

`"` matches the character `"` literally